# Firebase observer not observing database changes when called in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function which I'd like to act as an observer for user values, as well as setting some initial values when the view is presented.

```
func getParticipantInfo() {
    let groupRef = databaseRef.child("groups").child(currentRoomIdGlobal)
    groupRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in
        if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
            for each in snapDict {
                let uid  = each.key
                let avatar = each.value["profilePicture"] as! String
                let gender = each.value["gender"] as! String
                let handle = each.value["handle"] as! String
                let name = each.value["name"] as! String
                let status = each.value["status"] as! String

                // Set those to the dictionaries [UID : value]
                self.avatarDictionary.setValue(avatar, forKey: uid)
                self.nameDictionary.setValue(name, forKey: uid)
                self.genderDictionary.setValue(gender, forKey: uid)
                self.handleDictionary.setValue(handle, forKey: uid)
                self.statusDictionary.setValue(status, forKey: uid)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.createAvatar(senderId: uid, senderDisplayName: name, photoUrl: avatar,  color: UIColor.lightGray)
                    self.navCollectionView?.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

If I call this in `viewDidAppear`, this works perfectly. It grabs the user info from the database, sets the dictionaries, and everything works. On top of that, if someone new is added to the room (it's like a chat room), the function updates the dictionaries to include that new user's values.

However, I need to call it in `viewDidLoad`, not `viewDidAppear`. And when I do that, it works to set the initial values, but when someone is added to the room, that's not reflected in the app until I leave the view and come back again, so it's not "observing" the way it was in `viewDidAppear`.

Why does calling it in `viewDidLoad` all of a sudden make it stop observing properly? How can I make it reflect changes in real time the way it was in `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: I thought I read somewhere the best practice is to set this in viewWillAppear

Comment: Does my answer not answer your question.

Comment: What is the purpose of *for each in snapDict*? .childAdded loads one child at a time so there should be nothing to iterate over. It seems that loop would run once so it would be unneeded.

Comment: The code in the question can be called from viewDidLoad. However, it could vary depending on how things are being initialized. Can you update your question to include the code (snippet only please!) showing how the view is created and also the viewDidLoad function?

Comment: What is your data structure. Your code makes it seems as though you have an object groups with a bunch of children and you are iterating over the information inside those children. Is that what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I don't now why but this fixed the problem for me. All that I had to do was change `.childAdded` to `.value` and everything started to work as I had expected it to. I know that this is probably not the best practice but it is a simple fix to the problem.

Comment: Making it `.value` results in a crash when the view loads. Not sure why...

Comment: @KingTim Interesting try removing the code in the Firebase Closure and trying .value, Is it possible that it is something in the closure that is causing a totally separate problem?

Comment: @KingTim .childAdded and .value are two very different things. .childAdded will iterate over every child in the node, one at at a time and presenting them in the snapshot. That matches the code in the question. Using .value loads *everything* in the node at one time and presents it in the snapshot. That snapshot needs to then be iterated over to capture each child node. Because of that, this answer would not be correct as the code would be different depending on which is used.

Comment: @KingTim what is your data structure